# Why does Wpf Popup.IsOpen=true stay open from ListBox?

Tags: wpf, listbox, popup

I have a window with a Button and a ListBox.

```
  <Window x:Class="ListBoxFail.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          Height="350" Width="525">
     <Grid>
        <Popup Name="Popup" StaysOpen="False">
           <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        </Popup>
        <Button Content="ClickMe" Click="OpenPopup" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox SelectionChanged="OpenPopup" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
           <ListBoxItem Content="One"/>
           <ListBoxItem Content="Two"/>
        </ListBox>
     </Grid>
  </Window>
```

The Button and the ListBox both trigger a Popup to open:

```
  namespace ListBoxFail {
     partial class MainWindow {
        public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
        private void OpenPopup(object a, object b) { Popup.IsOpen = true; }
     }
  }
```

When you click the button, the popup opens. Clicking anywhere else then closes the popup as expected.

When you click in the ListBox, the popup opens. However, the only way to close the popup at this point is to have the main window lose focus. Clicking around the window or clicking the button does not close the popup.

What gives? Why is it that the **ListBox ignores the StaysOpen=false directive?** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong per se. The ListBox and its focus events can be a little 'iffy'. I would suggest looking into how focus events work on the ListBox, however it might be worth considering the below:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This may be worth looking into, however if it doesn't appear to help or solve your problem let me know and we can take a closer look at the issue.